# Card() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial'

Tags: python, django

I'm putting together a CRUD interface without using the admin app, still pretty new to Python and Django, but when I go to create an entry, it throws out the error in my title.

here's the target page:

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  Card Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="name"><br>
  Mana Cost:<br>
  <input type="text" name="mana_cost"><br>
  Supertype:<br>
  <input type="text" name="supertype"><br>
  Keyword 1:<br>
  <input type="text" name="keyword_1"><br>
  Keyword 2:<br>
  <input type="text" name="keyword_2"><br>
  Keyword 3:<br>
  <input type="text" name="keyword_3"><br>
  Rules Text:<br>
  <input type="text" name="rules_text"><br>
  Power & Toughness:<br>
  <input type="text" name="power_toughness"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Add Card"><br>
{% endblock %}
```

my views.py:

```
from task99_app import forms
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from django.views.generic.edit import DeleteView
from .models import Card
# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

class CardList(ListView):
    model = Card

class CardCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = Card

class CardDetail(DetailView):
    model = Card

class CardUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Card

class CardDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Card
```

my forms.py:

```
from django import forms


class CardForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=80)
    mana_cost = forms.CharField(max_length=12)
    supertype = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    keyword_1 = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    keyword_2 = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    keyword_3 = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    rules_text = forms.CharField(max_length=500)
    power_toughness = forms.CharField(max_length=10)
```

and my models.py:

```
from django import forms

class CardForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=80)
    mana_cost = forms.CharField(max_length=12)
    supertype = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    keyword_1 = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    keyword_2 = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    keyword_3 = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    rules_text = forms.CharField(max_length=500)
    power_toughness = forms.CharField(max_length=10)
```

I've seen a few instances of this happening to others, but I don't understand their code well enough to understand how to fix mine, but I feel so close.

EDIT: urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from task99_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'form/$', views.CardCreate.as_view(), name='card_create'),
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'card_list/$', views.CardList.as_view(), name='card_list'),
    url(r'card/<int:pk>', views.CardDetail.as_view(), name='card_details'),
    url(r'delete/<int:pk>', views.CardDelete.as_view(), name='card_delete'),
    url(r'update/<int:pk>', views.CardUpdate.as_view(), name='card_update'),
    ]
```

Comment: can you share your `urls.py` file as well

Answer (score 0):

In your `CardCreate` view, you have used the *model* as `form_class`, not your `Form`:

```
class CardCreate(CreateView):
    model = Card
    form_class = CardForm
```

**EDIT 1**: Note that in your `UpdateView`, you forgot to set a `form_class`. That is not per se necessary, but then you need to specify [**`fields`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.fields). You can however use the same `form_class`:

```
class CardUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Card
    form_class = CardForm
```

Furthermore you need to specify the model in your `CardForm`:

```
class CardForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=80)
    mana_cost = forms.CharField(max_length=12)
    supertype = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    keyword_1 = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    keyword_2 = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    keyword_3 = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    rules_text = forms.CharField(max_length=500)
    power_toughness = forms.CharField(max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        model = Card
        fields = '__all__'
```

**EDIT 2**: Note that in your `urls.py` you use path syntax in `url(..)`s, you should use [**`path(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#django.urls.path) instead:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('form/', views.CardCreate.as_view(), name='card_create'),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('card_list/', views.CardList.as_view(), name='card_list'),
    path('card/<int:pk>', views.CardDetail.as_view(), name='card_details'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>', views.CardDelete.as_view(), name='card_delete'),
    path('update/<int:pk>', views.CardUpdate.as_view(), name='card_update'),
]
```

Comment: Upon doing that, the page now throwsa back a "ModelForm has no model class specified." error. Any tips on that?

Comment: @Etherealscorpions: well you forgot to specify the model in your `CardForm`.

Comment: Ah, my bad. The word 'model' has started looking not real anymore.

Comment: Alright, applying that, I can now get to the form in question. Hitting confirm, however, brings me to a 'Reverse for 'card_details' with arguments '(1,)' not found.' error.

Comment: @Etherealscorpions: that is normal, you use syntax for `path(..)`s, but use `url(..)`, you can not mix the two. Convert the urls to `path(..)` instead.

Comment: That fixed it. Had a quick tussle with get_success_url, but 
```
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('card_list')
```
took care of that. I think that just about wraps this project up. Thank you so much for your help, I gotta take a break from Python for a bit to relax, I think.